# "Error: Python not found" when trying to access the android repository

Tags: android, python, git, repository

It gives me the error on line 23 of the repo file:

> exec: python: not found.

the thing is, I have python installed in C:\Python27 (the default)
I'm using the Git Bash when typing in these commands. I've tried to move the python folder into the git directory to run the repo file and it still says the same thing.

I've tried to run the python interpreter and then run the repo file, but it says the same thing.

Anybody have any suggestions? I just wanna download the android source code through the git and repo.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you should add python to your path variable.